# getting date patterns from DataFrame in pandas by python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file which contains different types of date format.how i get patterns by using regex with out for loop.

```
0        1/7/2022
1        1/8/2022
2      Jan/9/2022
3       1/10/2022
4      25/11/2022
5       1/12/2022
6       21/9/2022
7       1/14/2022
8       1/15/2022
9     May/16/2022
10      7/17/2022
11      1/18/2022
```

I need to get patterns from this file. "I dont want to. change. format too"

I tried in this format

```
df_date['Date ']=df_date['Date '].astype(str).replace([r'\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4}'], 'D', regex=True)
```

Comment: Is the `35362` at the end a typo?

Comment: Hi i need to get date patterns how many in the file

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is actually pretty good at figuring this out automatically.
Use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) without specifying the format. Only decide if ambiguous dates are day first or not (e.g. 1/7 could be 1st of July or 7th of January).

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce', dayfirst=True)
```

Output:

```
0    2022-07-01
1    2022-08-01
2    2022-01-09
3    2022-10-01
4    2022-11-25
5    2022-12-01
6    2022-09-21
7    2022-01-14
8    2022-01-15
9    2022-05-16
10   2022-07-17
11   2022-01-18
12          NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: my question is how to get different patterns in dataframe?

Comment: @divya then the question is unclear, you should provide the expected output with details on the logic

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY    
1   MM/DD/YYYY  
2   MM/DD/YYYY  
3   MM/DD/YYYY  
4   25/11/2022  
5   MM/DD/YYYY  
6    21/9/2022  
7   MM/DD/YYYY  
8   MM/DD/YYYY  
9   MM/DD/YYYY  
10    MMDDYYYY  
11  MM/DD/YYYY  
12   10-3-2021